# The function doesn't work when I output python opencv .exe

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv, exe

I have a project with python opencv that plays video on 4 screens according to the data coming from the serial port. it works correctly on the code editor. But when I get the .exe output of the program, it runs the main.py file again instead of playing the video according to the incoming data. Below are the codes of my seriport.py file. What is the reason or solution for this, what should I pay attention to.

```
#seriport.py

import os
import cv2
import json
import time
import serial
import threading
import multiprocessing
import serial.tools.list_ports
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, QObject

class SerialPort(QObject):
    connection_status_changed = pyqtSignal(str)  # Bağlantı durumu sinyali

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ser = None  # Seri port nesnesi
        self.islem_listesi = []
        self.process_listesi = []  # İşlem nesnelerini saklayacak liste
        self.ekranlar = {
            1: 0,
            2: 0,
            3: 0,
            4: 0
        }

    def initialize_serial(self):
        port = self.find_serial_port()  # Seri portu otomatik olarak bul
        if port:
            try:
                # Seri port bağlantısını otomatik olarak başlat
                self.ser = serial.Serial(port, baudrate=9600)
                print("Seri port bağlantısı başlatıldı.")
                self.connection_status_changed.emit("Bağlı")  # Bağlantı durumu sinyali gönder
                # Seri port işlemini arka plan iş parçasında çalıştır
                serial_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.serial_thread_function)
                serial_thread.daemon = True  # Arka planda çalışan iş parçasının ana program sonlandığında sonlanmasını sağlar
                serial_thread.start()
                return "bağlandı"

            except serial.SerialException as e:
                print("Seri port bağlantısı başlatılamadı:", e)
                self.close_serial()
        else:
            print("Bağlı seri port bulunamadı.")

        return "Bağlantı Hatası"

    def serial_thread_function(self):
        while True:
            if self.ser is not None:
                try:
                    veri = self.ser.readline().decode('utf-8').strip()  # Seri porttan veri okuma
                    print("veri geldi: ", veri)
                    if "_" in veri:
                        sira_no_str, aktiflik_durumu = veri.split("_")
                        
                        if not sira_no_str.isdigit():
                            print("Hatalı sira_no: ", sira_no_str)
                            continue
                        sira_no = int(sira_no_str)
                        ekran = (sira_no - 1) // 5 + 1
                        
                        if aktiflik_durumu == "1":
                            if ekran in self.ekranlar:
                                if self.ekranlar[ekran] == 1:
                                    print("Ekran dolu.")
                                elif self.ekranlar[ekran] == 0:
                                    if sira_no not in self.islem_listesi:
                                        self.islem_listesi.append(sira_no)
                                        indeks = self.islem_listesi.index(sira_no)
                                        self.ekranlar[ekran] = 1
                                        process_name = "p" + sira_no_str
                                        process = multiprocessing.Process(target=VideoKontrol.oynatma_fonksiyonu, args=(ekran, sira_no, aktiflik_durumu), name=process_name)
                                        process.start()
                                        self.process_listesi.append(process)  # İşlem nesnesini listeye ekleyin
                                    else:
                                        print("Bu sira_no zaten kullanılıyor.")
                                else:
                                    print("Hatalı ekran numarası.")
                            else:
                                print("Geçersiz ekran numarası.")
                                
                        elif aktiflik_durumu == "0":
                            if sira_no in self.islem_listesi:
                                indeks = self.islem_listesi.index(sira_no)
                                process_name = "p" + sira_no_str
                                process = None
                                for p in self.process_listesi:
                                    if p.name == process_name:
                                        process = p
                                        break
                                if process:
                                    process.terminate()
                                    process.join()
                                    self.process_listesi.remove(process)  # İşlem nesnesini listeden çıkartın
                                del self.islem_listesi[indeks]
                                self.ekranlar[ekran] = 0
                            else:
                                print("Video zaten oynatılmıyor.")
                        else:
                            print("Geçersiz aktiflik durumu.")
                    else:
                        break

                except serial.SerialException as e:
                    print("Seri porttan veri okunamadı:", e)
                    self.close_serial()
                    time.sleep(1)
                    port = self.find_serial_port()
                    if port:
                        print("Yeniden seri port bağlantısı başlatılıyor...")
                        self.ser = serial.Serial(port, baudrate=9600)
                        #self.ser = serial.Serial("COM4", baudrate=9600)
                    else:
                        print("Bağlı seri port bulunamadı. Yeniden denemek için bekleniyor...")
                        time.sleep(5)

    def close_serial(self):
        if self.ser is not None:
            self.ser.close()
            print("Seri port bağlantısı kapatıldı.")
            self.connection_status_changed.emit("Bağlı Değil")  # Bağlantı durumu sinyali gönder

    def find_serial_port(self, max_attempts=3):
        attempts = 0
    
        while attempts < max_attempts:
            # Bağlı seri portları listele
            available_ports = list(serial.tools.list_ports.comports())
            
            for port in available_ports:
                try:
                    if port.device == 'COM1':
                        continue
                    
                    test_ser = serial.Serial(port.device, baudrate=9600)
                    test_ser.write(b'<')  # "<" karakterini gönder
                    response = test_ser.read_until(b'vemedya')
                    test_ser.timeout = 1
                    test_ser.close()
                    
                    if b'vemedya' in response:
                        return port.device
                except serial.SerialException:
                    pass
            
            attempts += 1
        
        return None

    def is_serial_connected(self):
        return self.ser is not None and self.ser.is_open

    def stop_serial(self):
        self.close_serial()
        
        
        # Diğer değişkenleri sıfırlayın
        self.islem_listesi = []
        self.ekranlar = {
            1: 0,
            2: 0,
            3: 0,
            4: 0
        }
        
        # Çalışan işlemleri sonlandırın
        for process in self.process_listesi:
            if process.is_alive():
                process.terminate()
                process.join()
        
        self.process_listesi = []
        
class VideoKontrol:
    print("Buraya girdi 1")
    @staticmethod
    def oynatma_fonksiyonu(ekran, sira_no, aktiflik_durumu):
        try:
            ekran = int(ekran)
            video = int(sira_no)
            oynatma_durumu = int(aktiflik_durumu)
        except ValueError:
            print("Geçersiz girişler. Tüm değerler tamsayı olmalıdır.")
            return
        
        if ekran < 1 or ekran > 4:
            print("Geçersiz ekran numarası. 1 ile 4 arasında bir değer seçin.")
            return
        
        if video < 1 or video > 20:
            print("Geçersiz video numarası. 1 ile 8 arasında bir değer seçin.")
            return
        
        if oynatma_durumu == 1:
            # JSON dosyasını okuyun
            with open('config.json', 'r') as config_file:
                config_data = json.load(config_file)
            
            video_key = f"video{video}"  
            # Video yolu için config.json içindeki değeri alın
            video_name = config_data["videolar"][video_key]  
                
            # Video yolunu oluşturun
            video_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "videolar", video_name)
            cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)
            fps = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))

            if not cap.isOpened():
                print(f"Video açılamadı: {video_path}")
                return
            
            cv2.namedWindow(f"Ekran {ekran}", cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN)
            cv2.setWindowProperty(f"Ekran {ekran}", cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN, cv2.WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)

            while True:
                ret, pencere = cap.read()
                if not ret:
                    print(f"Video sona erdi: {video_path}")
                    # Video sonuna geldiğinde başa dön
                    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, 0)
                    continue

                cv2.imshow(f"Ekran {ekran}", pencere)
                
                # Videonun hızını ayarlamak için bekleme süresini hesaplayın
                wait_time = int(1000 / (fps*4))  # Milisaniye cinsinden bekleme süresi hesaplaması

                key = cv2.waitKey(wait_time)
                if key == ord('q'):
                    break
            
            cap.release()
        elif oynatma_durumu == 0:
            print("video durduruldu")
            cv2.destroyWindow(f"Ekran {ekran}")
    print("Buraya girdi 2")
```

What could be the reason why it works correctly in the code editor but works incorrectly when I get .exe output. Thank you very much in advance for your advice.